# Finding specific URLs from a list of URLs using Python

Tags: python, web-crawler

I want find if specific links exist in a list of URLs by crawling through them. I have written the following program and it works perfectly. However, I am stuck at 2 places.

1. Instead of using an array, how can I call the links from a text file.
2. The crawler takes close to 4 minutes to crawl through 100 webpages.

Is there a way I can make that faster.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer
import urllib2
import re
import threading

start = time.time()
#Links I want to find
url = "example.com/one", "example.com/two", "example.com/three"]

#Links I want to find the above links in...
url_list =["example.com/1000", "example.com/1001", "example.com/1002",
"example.com/1003", "example.com/1004"]

print_lock = threading.Lock()
#with open("links.txt") as f:
#  url_list1 = [url.strip() for url in f.readlines()]

def fetch_url(url):
    for line1 in url_list:
        print "Crawled" " " + line1
        try:
            html_page = urllib2.urlopen(line1)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
            link = soup.findAll(href=True)
        except urllib2.HTTPError:
        pass
        for link1 in link:
            url1 = link1.get("href")
            for url_input in url:
                if url_input in url1:
                    with print_lock:
                        print 'Found' " " +url_input+ " " 'in'+ " " + line1

threads = [threading.Thread(target=fetch_url, args=(url,)) for url in url_list]
for thread in threads:
thread.start()
for thread in threads:
thread.join()
print('Entire job took:',time.time() - start)
```

Comment: Thanks Cory. Always struggle with that.

Comment: . I've made the edits based on a few examples. The program is much faster, however the output is printing the same answer several times and sometimes the output is wrong. I used the lock() function to prevent it... not working. I still haven't figured out multithreading yet. Any help here is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to read from a textfile, use the code you commented out.

As for the "performance" problem: Your code blocks at the read operation `urlopen` until the content from the website is returned. You ideally want to run those requests in parallel. You need a parallelized solution, by using threads for example.

[Here's](https://github.com/gevent/gevent/blob/master/examples/concurrent_download.py) an example using a different approach, using gevent (non-standard)

Comment: What do you mean Python doesn't naturally support [multithreading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html)?

Comment: multithreading != multiprocessing. You don't want to fork 100 processes to do 100 requests

Comment: Could you explain yourself a little more? Python also supports [threading](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html), which "*is still an appropriate model if you want to run multiple I/O-bound tasks simultaneously.*"

Comment: I just looked it up. I don't know why, but my brain strongly believed that python does not support multithreading. I am sorry for this misinformation! I edited my answer.

Comment: Thanks all. I've made the edits based on a few examples. The program is much faster, however the output is printing the same answer several times and sometimes the output is wrong. I used the lock() function to prevent it... not working. I still haven't figured out multithreading yet. Any help here is highly appreciated. Thanks in advance.