# Printing web crawler output

Tags: python, python-2.7, flask, web-crawler

I want to create a web interface for the web crawler I [wrote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32425480/finding-specific-urls-from-a-list-of-urls-using-python/32425585#32425585) in Python, using Flask. I was not able to print the result, so thought of displaying a list instead. How can print the results of the `for` loop in the `login.html` page?

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, redirect, url_for, request

from bs4 import BeautifulSoup, SoupStrainer

import urllib2

import re

from flask import jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/login', methods=['GET', 'POST'])

def login():
    url = "example.com"

    url_list = ["example.com/1", "example.com/2"]
    found_list = []

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['inpur_url'] != 'example.com':
            error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
        else:
            for line1 in url_list:
                 #print "Crawled" " " + line1
                 try:
                     html_page = urllib2.urlopen(line1)
                     soup = BeautifulSoup(html_page)
                     link = soup.findAll(href=True)
                 except urllib2.HTTPError:
                   pass
                 for link1 in link:
                     url1 = link1.get("href")
                     if url in url1:
                         found_list.append(url)
                 return jsonify(found_list)     

    #return render_template('login.html', error=error)
    return jsonify(found_list)     

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Comment: @jonrsharpe Thank you. Still struggle with that

Comment: Just paste the code in, select it all, and hit Ctrl-K or the `{}` button. Don't just scatter backticks everywhere.

Comment: Thank you. Will definitely keep that in mind

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about your overall design decision, but I'm pretty sure the logic in your function isn't actually going to find the links within the web pages.  This will utilize urllib2 and BeautifulSoup to get you the list of links:

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    if request.form['inpur_url'] != 'example.com':
        error = 'Invalid Credentials. Please try again.'
    else:
        for url in url_list:
            try:
                handle = urllib2.urlopen(url)
                contents = handle.read()
                soup = BeautifulSoup(contents)
                links = soup.find_all("a")
                for link in links:
                    found_list.append(link.get("href"))
            except urllib2.HTTPError:
                pass
```

Comment: Thank you. I can find the links within the webpages... but I don't know how to print the result using flask.

Comment: Try using the json module within flask: 
"from flask import json"
And then "return json.dumps(found_list)"